# JavaFx and ControlsFx PopOvers

Tags: javafx, popover, controlsfx

we have to program a GUI application for our company.
In this application we are using the controlsfx library for the PopOvers.

We noticed that sometimes the GUI freeze when we have an PopOver open and we change the height of the PopOver. 
For example, we have some textfields, checkboxes and so on in the PopOver. With some checkboxes we can expand extra textfields to show more options. By expand the extra fields the height of the PopOver becomes bigger.
On that point the GUI freezes sometimes.

It happens more often when the resolution of the display is "low".

With debugging and Visual VM i see that the function computeShapeBounds is maybe the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5emL1.png)

Windows showing me the following error message:

```
Problemsignatur:
Problemereignisname:    AppHangB1
Anwendungsname: javaw.exe
Anwendungsversion:  8.0.710.15
Anwendungszeitstempel:  5679f9aa
Absturzsignatur:    662c
Absturztyp: 0
Betriebsystemversion:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Gebietsschema-ID:   1031
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 1:  662cd1888af30ec9c5cadbe93a4e57cd
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 2:  b662
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 3:  b662c7a56753729d3c10d85757851292
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 4:  662c
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 5:  662cd1888af30ec9c5cadbe93a4e57cd
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 6:  b662
Zusätzliche Absturzsignatur 7:  b662c7a56753729d3c10d85757851292
```

Errors happens on all Windows 7 64Bit machines with JRE 1.8_71 (and lower).
Application build with JDK 1.8_45.
We are using ControlsFx version 8.40.10.

Does anybody had the same issues with ControlsFx or know a workaround?

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are the author of this bug report there is at least someone else having a similar problem.

https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/620/app-hangs-when-popover-grows-too-much

Comment: Sry for late answer.
Thanks for the link, seems to be the same problem. I will kepp an eye on these report.